# Use of getdelim

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
  FILE *fp;
  char *lineptr = NULL;
  size_t len;
  size_t read;
  fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

  if(NULL == fp) {
    exit(1);
  }

  while((read = getdelim(&lineptr, &len, 33, fp)) != -1) {
    printf("%s", lineptr);
  }

  free(lineptr);
}
```

In `test.txt` I have written:

```
before giving tab !after tab has been given
```

I have set `!` as the delimiter but I don't see any difference between `getline` and `getdelim` in `getdelim` I can set the delimter but in case of `getline` it is newline character, I want the o/p to be:

```
 before giving tab
 after tab has been given
```

`!` should be taken as delimiter. How can I do this using `getdelim`?

Comment: are you sure you don't just want `printf("%s\n",lineptr);`?

Comment: Note that you just can use `'!'` instead of `33`...

Answer (score 6):

This is not tested, but try to change your printf line, so you can see the difference:

```
printf("%s\n",lineptr);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's doing exactly what you think it is, it's just that the first string it prints is

```
before giving tab !
```

with no new line, followed by `after tab has been given`

change your print to

```
printf("%s\n",lineptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working perfectly fine (and delimiting on '!' as you requested); the only problem is that you are printing out the individual strings exactly as they come in, in a while loop.

Remember: getdelim includes the delimiter in the string (it won't remove the '!' for you).

For the given test case, the first time around the loop will give the string `"before giving tab !"`, and the second time around the loop will give the string `"after tab has been given"`. You are printing them both out without any newlines or anything, so your output looks just the same as the input. I suggest you print a newline after each string, but that won't get rid of the '!'. So you may want to change your print code to:

```
while((read=getdelim(&lineptr,&len,33,fp))!= -1)
{
    if (lineptr[strlen(lineptr)-1] == '!')
        lineptr[strlen(lineptr)-1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",lineptr);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `strlen()`, use `read` instead, which is the number of characters stored in `lineptr`, not counting the null terminator: `lineptr[read-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char before[256], after[256];

fscanf(fp, "%255[^!]!%255[^\n]", before, after);
printf("%s\n%s", before, after);
```

Answer (score 0):

See `man getdelim`. The delim is included in the string, followed by a null character. If you want to print a string followed by an EOL, puts is the fastest way.

```
puts(lineptr);
```

If you also want to remove the delim '!', add this before the puts.

```
lineptr[read - 1] = 0;
```